# How to flash Ubuntu-core Snappy on Artik-5 (v 0.5)?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Artik 5 already have an OS fedora 22. I followed the link to boot from SD card, and got success:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/samsung-artik-iot-modules/

But I cannot flash Ubuntu-core to Artik 5. Instead of writing to eMMC, it boots from SD card when SW2 (1:on 2:off) or (1:on 2:on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as of now to flash the eMMc as far as I know of. We have in the plan to have a tool to flash current Ubuntu Core image that you would start from ssd card to eMMC (but no ETA on this).

Comment: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.devel.snappy/1452/match=artik